# How to make Keywords section for IEEEtrans conf. document class TeX file

Tags: ieeetran, abstract, keywords

I need to make below code as the Keywords of my paper in `IEEEtran` conference document class:

```
\par \textbf{\textit{Keywords$—$}}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Please (1) post a complete, small document, and (2) tell us what you want help with. Frankly, I have no idea what you are asking. And what does this have to do with hyphenation or the abstract?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll do that next time. Gonzalo has kindly made it work.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina 's crystal ball is evidently in better working order than mine ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class provides the `IEEEkeywords` environment; the default header is "Index Terms", but you can change this with a redefinition of `IEEEkeywordsname`

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
We will discuss the most important subject. 
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Broad band networks, quality of service, WDM.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\end{document}
```

[image]